# MediaWiki MySQL Database Character set, which one to use?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, mediawiki, arabic

I'm installing MediaWiki and am confused which charset to use.
I installed MediaWiki before but never took care of this: I used the default choice (which is Binary), and it didn't cause any problem, but now it's different and I can make no mistake.

The wiki I'm installing is mainly using **Arabic**, the language is Arabic.

Which Database charset should I use?

Answer (score 12):

Use the default, `binary`. Historically, it was the only option when MySQL's Unicode support was so broken that it corrupted [non-BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) characters. Later, `utf8` was added to MediaWiki as an experiment, but it resulted in corruption for some weird languages. Not so long ago, `utf8mb4` charset was finally introduced in MySQL 5.5 that fixes this problem, but it isn't supported by MW yet.

Comment: Do you know if this is still correct after all this time (shot in the dark I know)

Comment: Yup, nothing changed.

Comment: See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDBTableOptions for how you can configure your MediaWiki Table Options and https://wiki.freephile.org/wiki/Collation for more info on inspecting or altering your collation and charset.